# Android: Making an app with a lot of pages

Tags: java, android, xml

So I'm getting very comfortable with android and would like to make a trivia quiz-like app that will have 100+ questions. Question pages will all be very similar: they will have a 30sec timer, a question, and 4 options. Once you get a question right you move on to the next (at random). What is the best and most efficient way to go about this?

Do I - Create 100 xml page-layouts and classes for each (doesn't sound like the most efficient way)

Or is there any way I could do this without having a new layout and class for each question?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think you would need 100 xml page layouts since they will all be the same (or very similar).  You will just need an xml layout for your question page that includes a text field for you question, and a radio (or similar) section of 4 buttons for your answers.

I would then create a Question class that includes your question and answers. ex.

```
public class Question {
    private String _question;
    private int _correctAnswerIndex;
    private Object[] _answers;

    public Question(String question, Object answers[], int correctAnswerIndex) {
        _question = question;
        _correctAnswerIndex = correctAnswerIndex;
        _answers = answers;
    }

    // Plus your getters and setters
}
```

Then in your activity (or fragment) that displays the question you can set the content view to your layout, retrieve the appropriate fields and populate them accordingly.

ex.

```
public class QuestionActivity extends Activity {
    private ArrayList<Question> _questions;
    private int _currentQuestionIndex;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.question_layout);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        //Add your questions...

        TextView questionField = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question_layout_question_field);
        questionField.setText(_questions.get(_currentQuestionIndex).getQuestion());

        //Get and set your other fields.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have the same layout for each question. Questions would be in an array of a class containing the question, 4 answer options and a marker for correct answer. Load element n by random function.

Answer (score 1):

If the question pages are similar you should reuse the same layout for every question.

You only need to populate the different TextViews in your layout with different information corresponding to each question.

If you have a object "Question" and an array of Questions with all your questions (for example) you could on the onCreate section pick a random question and populate the textviews with the Question parameters.

Answer (score 1):

put the questions into array of string[] then put the answers in the answer[] array with related index, ex: question[1] its answers will be answrs[4], [5], [6] and [7] or you can have 4 array of answers were each multiple choice reside in the same index of the question. then use random library to choose random question and relate to its answer...

let them all have them same layout and just whenever the questions changes.. settext to the chosen question... and so on..